# How can I restore acces to an external hard drive that was marked as hibernated on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive, hibernate

I used my external hard drive on a Windows 10 computer at my university to transfer some files for a conference, the files were fully transfered at least 2 hours before I left, when I unplugged the external hard drive from the computer.

A couple of months later when I wanted to use it again on my Fedora 32 installation I couldn't get it to mount, and I found this question [HDD with Windows boot locked because of hibernation flag](https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag) which points that my hard drive is "locked" in hibernation mode.

Obviously I can't go back to said computer, and because I knew I was going to have access to a Win10 machine soon enough I didn't try any of the actions as it has a higher risk than on Windows apparently.

So now I am on a Windows 10 machine, but I have no idea what steps I should do, a lot of things seem to point to use `chkdsk` but I don't know which options to use as apparently some can lead to more data loss?

Any pointers into what arguments I should use or other tool/commands before I try anything?

Comment: Delete the hiberfil.sys file on that drive.

Comment: And how can I achieve this? Windows is refusing to let me open the drive because it considers it "Corrupted". Is there a way via CMD/Powershell?

Comment: Boot from a live usb and delete from there.>>>use the free evaluation>>>https://www.lsoft.net/bootdisk/